# Browser does not show anything when i open the react app by npm start

Tags: reactjs

Every time I start the react app by closing the Chrome browser , the browser does not show anything and in vs code all the files show the Untracked(U) symbol
How this thing can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you see any error in console ? or any error in the terminal while running the project.
2. 'U' stands for untracked file, meaning a file that is new or changed but has not yet been added to the repository.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).